# Changing A record to CNAME Propagation using AWS Route 53

Tags: azure, amazon-route53, cname, azure-front-door

We currently have an API set up which is configured using an A record pointing to a fixed IP address set up in AWS Route 53

e.g. api.servicename.co.uk  -> 123.123.123.123 (Type A, routing policy set to Simple)

The API service resides in Azure and we have created a new version behind Azure Front Door which does not support Fixed IP addresses.

When I change the A record to a CNAME and re-point to the URL the service fails. I'm aware propagation can take some time so is there a better approach as I need to avoid any downtime?